# How to fix the issue “Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2” in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, react-native, build-error

When I run the application then the following error is showing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an error like this is not really your fault but rather something messed up in/by Xcode. In this case I often erase or move my derived data folder so next time I build it has to start fresh.

You can find your derived data as described https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-delete-derived-data-and-clean.html. Once you've found it you can delete it, or if you're a cautious cat you can rename or move the folder so Xcode can't find it. In case you want it back later.

Best of luck!